# Multiple events in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I am trying to program the Pokemon Trading Card Game using Visual C# 2010 but I ran into a little problem. I have three objects:

**Game**: Handles all of the game’s data and rules.

**Form1**: The window shown to the player. Displays all the info the player is allowed to see about the game and allows the player to interact with the game.

**ComputerAI**: This object tracks what the computer is supposed to know and holds the AI’s logic.

To keep things moving, the game raises a “PriorityChanged” event, to let both the player and the AI know that priority has changed and which one received it (in the EventArgs). The Form reports this info in a log and displays the messages: “Waiting for you” and “Waiting for opponent” as appropriate. The computerAI uses it to decide if it should run its logic or not. The problem I ran into was that when the event was raised the AI was told and ran its logic (playing cards etc), this caused the player to get priority and raised another PriorityChanged event, which the AI got and did nothing with (which was correct). Then the Form got both PriorityChanged events one after the other but in the wrong order.

To fix this I split the “PriorityChanged” event into two, “PriorityChanged” and “PriorityRecieved”. The Forms updates the display on the “PriorityChanged” event, and the AI runs its logic on the “PriorityRecieved” event.

**This solution worked, but it strikes me as wrong. Is there a better way?**

Comment: probably a question for programmers.stackexchange.com  (as it's subjective)

Comment: I agree. Since your change worked, there's not much to answer here.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that I didn't stumble into some anti-pattern, or that there isn't some other standard way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what was occurring is the following:

```
PriortyChanged (Start)
  AI -> Process
  AI -> Raise Priority Changed
    Priority Changed (Start)
      AI -> DoNothing
      UI -> Process
    Priority Changed (End)
  UI -> Process
PriorityChanged (End)
```

Comment: That's exactly what was happening. The code handling the PriorityChanged event causes another PriorityChanged event to be raised. This became a bigger problem when I set up two AIs to play against each other. The game ended with approx. 300 items on the call stack.